# {filename} Variable Outputting Full Path

Tags: assets, matrix

Assets 2.0.3; EE 2.5.5

My Assets field is inside a Matrix cell. The Matrix field is named `index_slides`, and the Assets cell is named `full`. I want to output just the filename of the file (myfile.jpg). Here's the code I'm using:

```
{index_slides}
    {full}
        <p>The name of this file is {filename}</p>
    {/full}
{/index_slides}
```

Instead of outputting "myfile.jpg" as expected, it outputs the full file path ("http://mysite.com/my/upload/dir/myfile.jpg"), which should be what the `{url}` variable is for.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this myself.

Comment: I also can not reproduce this.  kgrote - is that your entire template code?  More template context would help quite a lot here, I suspect.  Thank you!

Comment: Where is the image located – an EE upload directory or Amazon S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that I'm using a single variable farther up in the tag pair, like this:

```
{index_slides}
    {exp:ce_img:single
        src="{full}"
        width="500"
        height="300"
        alt="{alt}"
        crop="yes"
    }
    {full}
        <p>The name of this file is {filename}</p>
    {/full}
{/index_slides}
```

That seems to be getting Assets all confused, which is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

can you try by putting the code like:

```
{index_slides}
    {full}
        <p>The name of this file is {file_name}</p>
    {/full}
{/index_slides}
```

as asset cell also treat as file field type so it may work.